# How to convert a matrix to a Adjacency Matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I have the randomly generated Matrix. My main task is to create a Link Matrix.

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0] 
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Now, i want to iterate through each column meaning, for column 1 at index 0, I take the amount of 1's there is in the column which is 3 and divide each element in column by the number 1's - 3. And I would end up with

```
0
1/3
0
1/3
1/3
```

The output I want to achieve is:

```
[0, 0, 1/3, 0, 0],
[1/3, 0, 1/3, 1/2, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1],
[1/3, 0, 1/3, 0, 0],
[1/3, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Is there a function in python that works it out automatically?

Comment: Is it a numpy array or python list?

Comment: It is a numpy array.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: I did attempt it. Resulted with the values all being 0

Comment: Also I am not requesting the code, i am only asking how to implement it. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the sum over `axis=0` and divide the array by the array of sum at this axis:

```py
>>> array/array.sum(axis=0)
Out[198]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.33333333, 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.5       , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.5       , 1.        ],
       [0.33333333, 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.33333333, 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
```